# Tie-breaking for rounding to closest representable float in c?

Tags: c, floating-point

Still not clear after trying several experiments. We know that if we do `float a = X.XXXX` and the number is not representable by float, it would round to the closest representable number. But the question is what if rounding up and rounding down takes the same distance? What's the general rule for tie breaking?

Answer (score 1):

It's implementation defined. Assuming IEEE 754:

The standard defines 5 rounding modes, which might be used. The two modes of interest are:

- Round to nearest, ties to even (**this is the default for binary floating-point and the recommended default for decimal**)
- Round to nearest, ties away from zero

The 3 others are called directed rounding modes:

- Round towards zero
- Round towards - infinity
- Round towards infinity

Comment: Assuming system uses IEEE 754.

Comment: Nitpick: "directed rounding modes", instead of "direct rounding modes".

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, it *should* work like stated [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Rounding.html) (boldface mine):

> Round to nearest.
>   **This is the default mode**. It should be used unless there is a specific need for one of the others. In this mode results are rounded to the nearest representable value. **If the result is midway between two representable values, the even representable is chosen**. Even here means **the lowest-order bit is zero**.

Comment: That seems to cover only the GCC.

Comment: Since every implementation can handle the situation differently, this only applies to GCC. But there have to be similar docs for every compiler.